# SOA and ANY request disagree

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Recently, I had a problem with my site. The site wasnt opening properly and I figured it out that there was some problem with the SOA. I corrected the SOA record and now its working fine. But when I tried running a zonecheck (www.zonecheck.fr) on my domain as www.mydomain.org it shows me a fatal error which says that SOA and ANY request disagree. Could you please tell me what the error could be?

Thanks
niting

EDIT : Sorry guys I am little paranoid. The domain is www.bits-bosm.org. It gives different DNS results for bits-bosm.org and www.bits-bosm.org.

Comment: It is really mydomain.org or you are just making it up?

Comment: tell us the real domain so we can check....

Comment: As of today, the problem seems solved, Zonecheck does not report this error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with your zone:

```
$ dig +short SOA bits-bosm.org
ns1.bits-student.org. dnsadmin.subitspilani.bits-student.org. 2010041910 86400 7200 3600000 86400
$ dig +short CNAME www.bits-bosm.org
bits-bosm.org.
$ dig +short A bits-bosm.org
206.214.221.185
$ dig +short A www.bits-bosm.org
bits-bosm.org.
206.214.221.185
$ dig +short ANY bits-bosm.org
30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
10 aspmx.l.google.com.
20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
ns1.bits-student.org. dnsadmin.subitspilani.bits-student.org. 2010041910 86400 7200 3600000 86400
ns2.bits-student.org.
ns1.bits-student.org.
206.214.221.185
```